# Compare Databases in SQL Server 2008

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

I had to provide a web application creatde in ASP.net and C# to my client. After some time he wants to make changes in that product. I have to update in code and database. So please provide some idea or guidance that how to compare the database using SQL Server 2008.

Or can I do this with other software?

I have googled but I got not enough satisfaction. Thanks...

Comment: Do it using Visual studio 2012. Here in SQL- SQL-->Schema compare--> New schema comparison. Then upload your and client database and compare and update it. Thats all...

Comment: @Sandesh Ok you means It is done by only VS 2012 ....

Comment: No you have to use sql server 2008 or as per your requirement. You have use server , establish connection and then you can add database and continue to VS2012..

Comment: [Red-Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) for comparing the **structure** of the database, [Red-Gate SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to compare the **contents** (data) of the database.

Comment: You are doing it the wrong way round. While you are developing you have to save each change to the database as a SQL script in your version control system. Then apply the necessary scripts in production. There are tools to help you with that. Check out Liquibase or Flyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use [SQL Compare by Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/).

It's *very* easy to use - it will show you the differences between two databases and allow you to select which objects you want to synchronise. A synchronisation script is then generated that you can run on the target database.

Easy peasy!